# Сохранение фото на телефон

Tags: java, android, камера, файлы

Делаю приложение. Программа фотографирует в фоне дефолтной камерой. Тестировал на Nexus 4, на One Plus хорошо, все сохраняет. Пробую на Samsung, на любом из девайсов Samsung фотки не сохраняются. Не могу понять в чем проблема. Права есть, все должно быть нормально. Посоветуйте что делать.

Код для фотографии:

```
private void takePhoto(final Context context) {
    final SurfaceView preview = new SurfaceView(context);
    SurfaceHolder holder = preview.getHolder();
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            showMessage("Surface created");
            Camera camera = null;

            try {
                camera = Camera.open();
                showMessage("Opened camera");

                try {
                    camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }

                camera.startPreview();
                showMessage("Started preview");

                camera.takePicture(null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                        showMessage("Took picture");

                        saveAsImage(data);
                        camera.release();
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (camera != null)
                    camera.release();
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        @Override public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {}
        @Override public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {}
    });

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)context
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            1, 1,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
            0,
            PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);

    wm.addView(preview, params);
}
```

Код сохранения картинки в папку с фотками:

```
private void saveAsImage(byte[] data) {
    try {
        File cameraFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) + "/Camera");
        if(!cameraFile.exists())
            cameraFile.mkdir();
        File outputFile = new File(cameraFile, "/image_" + randomNumber() + ".jpg");
        FileOutputStream jpg = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        jpg.write(data);
        jpg.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Права:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Есть какие то идеи по этому поводу?

Целый день бьюсь и никак не могу понять, почему на всех девайсах кроме Samsung работает, а на Samsung не работает.

На Samsung создается папка `Camera`, а в ней фотографии, битые, то есть галереей или каким либо другим приложением. Вьювером его не просмотреть.

Comment: ни у кого нет идей?( Может я что-то где-то упустил?

Answer (score 2):

Делать кастомное приложения для фоток это весьма нетривиальная задача. Я делал в свое время, там было порядка 50 грязных фиксов и костылей для разных девайсов, где-то вспышка не выключалась, где-то фотка перевернутая, где-то разрешение не меняется, итд.

Рекомендую найти на Google Play приложение, *OpenCamera* - в описании указана ссылка на его исходный код, изучить его и сравнить со своим.

Comment: К сожалению http://sourceforge.net/p/opencamera/code/ линк не рабочий. Может у вас остались ваши исходники того приложения с костылями? Или хотя бы скажите в какую сторону копать что бы решать эту проблему?

Comment: лежит сайт sf, но зеркала по всему миру отлично работают. например: https://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/o/op/opencamera/

Comment: Что то я там не нашел решения) но спасибо